# OWASP ZAP - Scan a list of url

Tags: owasp, zap

I can use Manual Request Editor to scan 1 URL, how can I use it for a list of URL (e.g: list URLs in a CSV or text file)?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the 'Import URLs' add-on from the ZAP Marketplace: https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/wiki/HelpAddonsImporturlsImportUrls - that will allow you to import a file of URLs (one per line)

Comment: How can do this in case of using docker zap full scan ?

Comment: Are they all elated to the same site or are these multiple sites?

Comment: Same site.  May be we can use  the config parameter when we do  docker run ?. This question is reppted many times. an example inside doc will be very good.